# ValidationGroup Not working with Custom Asp.NET control

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom ASP.NET control that was created by inheriting from WebControls.ImageButton. In my markup I have the following

```
<td>
    <CustomControlLibrary:CustomIcon ID="icnSave" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="DoSomething"
        runat="server" Enabled="true" IconUse="Add" AutoSkin="true" SupportsEvents="true" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupA" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSave" OnClick="DoSomething" CausesValidation="true"
        runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupA">SAVE</asp:LinkButton>
</td>
```

When I click the "SAVE" link, the validation works as expected, however when I click on the CustomIcon, the validation does not work, and the DoSomething wired to the OnClick fires off.

Is there anything special that needs to be added to the custom controls to get ValidationGroups to work?  Note: The CustomIcon control itself does not have any special validation that it does/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i don't know this line .

```
<CustomControlLibrary:CustomIcon ID="icnSave" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="DoSomething"
        runat="server" Enabled="true" IconUse="Add" AutoSkin="true" SupportsEvents="true" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupA" />
```

If you want to image button ,please try this sample

```
<asp:textbox id="tb1" runat=Server />
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="ReqField1" controltovalidate="tb1"
validationgroup="valGroup1" errormessage="Required" runat=Server />

<asp:ImageButton id="Button2" causesvalidation=true
validationgroup="valGroup2" ImageUrl="img.gif" runat=Server />
```

[Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_prop_webcontrol_imagebutton_validationgroup)